# How to push UIViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have UIViewController in Viewbased application.
I want to push another UIViewcontroller from it.

```
-(IBAction) Myfunction
{

 MedicineSearchSystem *medicineSearchSystem = [[MedicineSearchSystem alloc]        initWithNibName:@"MedicineSearchSystem" bundle:nil];

 [self.parentViewController:medicineSearchSystem animated:YES]; // Crash here

}
```

Comment: In order to push a new view controller onto the stack, your existing view must have a `UINavigationController` as its parent. It appears that your code may have gotten mangled when you posted it, but the relevant method is `pushViewController:animated:`

Answer (score 1):

As warrenm already told you, first check if your viewController has a navigationController by calling something like : NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController) then you can push using:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:medicineSearchSystem animated:YES];

    self.mainItemListViewController = [[[NCItemsViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.mainItemListViewController];

[window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I have no navigationcontroller. Can I open 2nd viewcontroller from 1st viewcontroller.

Comment: you can do : [self presentModalViewController:animated:]

Comment: I have tried with presentModalViewController. But it does not work.

Comment: Is your class a UIViewController? It should work, it always works for me

Comment: I have UIViewController in Viewbased application. I want to push another UIViewcontroller from it.

Comment: So, the present method works right. If you want to push, you have to init the navigationController and set the firstViewController to be the root View Controller. then you can push